# How and why can a hook call itself without causing recursion?

Tags: hooks

When looking in WP hooks' code, I often see hooks that call themselves.

For example, this snippet from image_downsize():

```
function image_downsize($id, $size = 'medium') {

    if ( !wp_attachment_is_image($id) )
       return false;

    if ( $out = apply_filters( 'image_downsize', false, $id, $size ) ) {
       return $out;
    }
```

Why doesn't this cause recursion?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
apply_filters( 'image_downsize', false, $id, $size )
```

doesn't call the `image_downsize` *function*, it applies any filters hooked to the `image_downsize` tag, which would be a different function.

The only way that would cause recursion is if the filter you hook in turn called that function:

```
add_filter( 'image_downsize', 'wpd_downsize', 20, 3 );
function wpd_downsize( $return, $id, $size ){
    // collapse the universe
    return image_downsize( $id, $size );
}
```